# IntelliJ IDEA not show basic completion

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA 2016.2.4 does not show basic completion.
For example:
When I typed "String", no any auto-completion pop-up, then I pressed Ctrl + Space, it said "no suggestions", as in the image below:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA says "no suggestions"]

Then I pressed Ctrl + Space 2 more times, it showed this:

[image]

Then I pressed "Enter" and it resulted in this:

[image]

This is happenning to all Java basic classes such as: List, Map ...

My questions is how to make IntelliJ IDEA generated an import statement like "`import java.util.List`" instead of using full package name like this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Check that a correct JDK is configured for your project, and that `java.lang` isn't excluded from completion in `Preferences > Editor > General > Auto Import > Exclude from Import and Completion`.

Comment: Hi @BastienJansen, thank you for your comment.

I checked "File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Exclude from Import and Completion", and there is nothing in the box.

My project SDK is already configured to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64".

And still not working :(

Comment: Check in Project Structure that your module has a source root configured, and your file is under it (it also should have "(C)" icon in the Project View and not "j")

Comment: Hi guys, I found the cause, I used IntelliJ to open an existing project but I forgot to generate IntelliJ setting files with command: `gradle idea`, after running `gradle idea`, things back to normal.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm not using gradle. Latest update and still the same issue, have to press CTRL and space bar twice.